# PHP radio returns 'on' instead of value

Tags: php, html

I am making a form and the radio button html is

```
<p>Response Required?
  <label><input type="radio" name="required" vaule="yes" checked="checked">Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="required" value="no" >No</label>
</p>
```

however when looking at the $_POST data after the form is submitted I get [required] => on instead of a "yes" or "no" any thoughts?

Comment: There is a typo in your code I suppose. It should be `value` in the first radio button.

Answer (score 3):

Try first to fix "vaule" to "value".

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Response Required?
  <label><input type="radio" name="required" value="yes" checked="checked">Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="required" value="no" >No</label>
</p>
```

value spelling is wrong at 1st radio button

Comment: Actually he has two answers that are the same. So you have 50% probability to get your answer accepted :P